# Nested lists references not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I'm a noob in middle school. I have a short piece of code that isn't working:

```
board=[]
temp=[]

for var0 in range(17):
    temp.append('  ')
for var in range(17):
    board.append(temp)
class group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f=[]
        self.x=[]
        self.y=[]

groupb=[]
groupw=[]

while 1:
    for var0 in range(17):
        for var1 in range(17):
            if var1==16:
                print((board[var0])[16])
            else:
                print((board[var0])[var1],end='')
    move=input()
    move=(move.lower()).split()
    move[1]=int(move[1])
    move[2]=int(move[2])
    if move[0]=='b':
        board[move[1]][move[2]]=' b'
        for var0 in range(len(groupb)):
            if (move[1]-1 in groupb[var0].x or move[1]+1 in groupb[var0].x or move[1] in groupb[var0].x) and (move[2]-1 in groupb[var0].y or move[2]+1 in groupb[var0].y or move[2] in groupb[var0].y):
                (groupb[var0].x).append(move[1])
                (groupb[var0].y).append(move[2])
                temp=1
        if temp!=1:
            groupb.append('')
            groupb[len(groupb)-1]=group()
    elif move[0]=='w':
        board[move[1]][move[2]]=' w'
        for var0 in range(len(groupw)):
            if (move[1]-1 in groupw[var0].x or move[1]+1 in groupw[var0].x or move[1] in groupw[var0].x) and (move[2]-1 in groupw[var0].y or move[2]+1 in groupw[var0].y or move[2] in groupw[var0].y):
                (groupw[var0].x).append(move[1])
                (groupw[var0].y).append(move[2])
        if temp!=1:
            groupw.append('')
            groupw[len(groupb)-1]=group()
    else:
        print('TurnError')
```

But every time I try to run it, it spits out an entire column when I only want a  single character:

```
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b                        
     b
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm really confused.

Comment: what is your code supposed to do more broadly?

Comment: what are you trying to do? `    for var0 in range(17):
        for var1 in range(17):
            if var1==16:
                print((board[var0])[16])
            else:
                print((board[var0])[var1],end='')` is printing the 'b'

Comment: i am trying to make a go program. its an Asian board game also @karthikr, that prints the whole board. I suspect thats the problem, but i cant figure it out.

Comment: may you provide us the input you're typing in order to get the 'b's?

Comment: 'b 3 4', but the editor is slicing off 4 spaces at the front of the output.

Comment: One error appears in the first 5 lines. Wherein you create a list and then create a list which references that list for each of its elements rather than referencing copies. Fix replace `board.append(temp)` with `board.append(list(temp))`.

Comment: what do u mean? temp is already a list EDIT: Guess what- it fixed the whole program. @Dan D., post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan said, the answer is to change board.append(temp) to board.(list(temp)). It was referencing temp repeatedly.